# Disable keep-alive in Firefox

Tags: http, firefox, keep-alive

I am using `firefox 36.0.` I set the value of `network.tcp.keepalive.enabled` as false.. but in the request header I can still see connection:keep-alive

I need to disable it for some of my experiments. Anybody has any idea?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a bug on Firefox, as a temporary workaround you can try this:

```
network.http.keep-alive.timeout = 0
```

This preference only has an effect if `network.http.keep-alive` is true.

Comment: It actually does not solve by problem.. I tried with your option.. does not make any difference... :(

Comment: I had more success with a timeout of 1 (maybe 0 means infinite?). The header was still sent, but the connection died quickly.

Answer (score 2):

The correct parameter was
`network.http.keep-alive`
...but does not exist any more (!)

As far as I understand, they consider you should not do that with HTTP/1.1.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=770331#c17